# Scaling image to fullsize

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to scale an image to fullsize. Now, is it better to take an image or is it better to use an div with background style? Or should I use the body tag with an background? And how does it scale on other resolutions?

Comment: This question is too vague. In what context are you trying to display the image? Is it a background image? Banner image? What does full size mean? Full size of the page? Full size of the image?

Comment: You could make the `<img>` contain full width of its `parent div` that is `.img { width: 100%; height: 100%;} or use `background-size: cover`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a full size background image you can use `background-size:cover;` ,

if you want to use width and height you can use in your **img** tag width and

height like this :

```
<img src="img" alt="image" width="100%" height="100%">
```